# Django pagination - for loop in all pages

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop, pagination

I have a list of objects that I would like to display in an ul/li. For that I do the code below:

```
<ul id="myUL">
  {% for l in lpps %}
  <li id="lpps"><a href="#">{{ l.codeACL }} {{ l.libelle }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The problem is that in my view, I ask to display only 15 objects per page.
But I want to ignore this and display all the objects on all the pages.

Is there something like for l in lpps.page(all)...?

Comment: Little up... please

Answer (score 0):

django have forloop.counter ,
you can use that like

```
<ul id="myUL">
   {% for l in lpps %}
       {% if forloop.counter == 15 %}{% break %}{% endif %}
       <li id="lpps"><a href="#">{{ l.codeACL }} {{ l.libelle }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On the other hand, I have the following error: 
Invalid block tag: "break", expected "elif", "else", or "endif

Comment: So you can use comparing like {% if forloop.counter  <= 15 %} <li id="lpps"><a href="#">{{ l.codeACL }} {{ l.libelle }}</a></li> {% endif %}

Comment: That way, I always only have the 15 objects on the page.... <ul id="myUL">
 {% for l in lpps %}
  {% if forloop.counter <= 15 %}
  <li id="lpps"><a href="#">{{ l.codeACL }} {{ l.libelle }}</a></li>
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>